# Geometry of the outputs of linear congruential random number generators

Tags: random-number-generator, modular-arithmetic, congruence

I learned that possible $m$ long sequences produced by linear congruential random number generators(of the form $r_{i+1}\equiv ar_i+b \mod n$) fall on hyperplanes. Using this fact I have come to think it might be possible to significantly narrow down the number of possible output sequences. Sadly I found the information of this topic to be quite scattered around in various academic papers and similar. I would highly appreciate it if anyone could point me either to the appropriate resources or even provide an answer to this question. Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: Actually, it is fairly easy to reconstruct the internal coefficients from a handful of outputs (and thus reconstruct the entire output sequence); hence there would appear little need to rely on hyperplanes to 'restrict the output'

Comment: @poncho the reason I am trying to do so is because attempting to reverse the entire subset of outputs that would be valid if they were possible is impractical. If this could be narrowed down significantly though reversal might actually become faster than a simple brute force search.